# Keyboard shortcut for Close all tabs except current working tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

When working with multiple tabs what is the keyboard shortcut to close all other tabs excpet the current tab. There is way to do this from right clicking tab and clicking "Close Others"
[Close Others from clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ6Ot.png)

Comment: Under: `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` you can search for various shortcuts. I tried searching for it, but I'm actually not sure if VScode has that by default? I use the Vim extension and that has a command mode where i can type `:tabo` and it does what you're looking for. It can take a while to get use to Vim controls though.

Comment: I was able to use workbench.action.closeOtherEditors inside a macro. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023 there is no need for an additional macro.
Press: <kbd>ctrl + k + ctrl + s</kbd>  to open Keyboard Shortcuts, search for Close Other `View: Close Other Editors in Group` -> bind it to whatever you want. I liked my RStudio shortcut of <kbd>ctrl+shift+alt+w</kbd>

PS: there are also other interesting options like close all saved other tabs